# Vuetify Form Data Undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i'm trying my form data submit. when i try my code

```
form.append('subject',"hello"),
```

It is good working. but `form.append('subject', 'this.subject') => return` 'undefined'. how  do i solve it?

form.append('subject',"hello"), it is good working. but `form.append('subject', 'this.subject') => return` 'undefined'.

My `Write.vue` is :

```
<template>
<v-form @submit.prevent="sendPost" id="WriteForm" method="post">
   <v-btn icon type="submit" form="WriteForm"><v-icon>send</v-icon></v-btn>
   <v-text-field name="subject"></v-text-field>
   <v-textarea name="context"></v-textarea>
</v-form>
</template>



<script>
 export default {  
  data(){
   return{}
  },
  methods: {
   sendPost: function(){
     console.log(this.subject); //==> undefined :(
     console.log(this.context); //==> undefined :(
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add that properties to your data object and bind them to the `v-text-field` as follows :

```
data(){
   return{
     subject:'',
     context:''
      }
    }
```

and bind them using `v-model` directive in your template fields like :

```
<v-text-field name="subject" v-model="subject"></v-text-field>
<v-textarea name="context" v-model="context"></v-textarea>
```